# Why does the D# work in Pink Floyd's Mother guitar solo?

Tags: guitar, theory

I'm curious why the D# sounds good in the guitar solo of Pink Floyd's Mother.  You can check for example the tab [here](https://tabs.ultimate-guitar.com/tab/pink_floyd/mother_tabs_834614) - the 14p13 is a pull-off from E to D#, but D# isn't in the G major scale even though Mother is in the key of G major.

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a key change in the solo?  Also, D# is the leading tone to E minor (E harmonic minor) and that is the relative minor to G major.  In that context it does work.  I think he is clearly soloing in E minor.

Comment: I believe the solo resolves on a G and that all the rest of the notes other than the D# are in the G major scale for what it's worth.  Not sure that he's soloing in E minor but I don't know...

Answer (score 3):

Basically, D♯ doesn't mean he's playing the ♯5 in this case. He's playing the **♮7 in E minor.**

The solo is played in the key of E minor (which is G major's relative minor), and a common thing to do when in minor is to raise the 7th degree, often for harmonic purposes *(it creates a leading tone, because D♯ resolves better to E than D does)*. You'd never guess that they call it harmonic minor. Another common thing to do is to raise both the 7th and the 6th, making melodic minor.

So, one is soloing in E minor, the relative minor of G major, and one uses the harmonic minor scale to get that D♯ in the solo.

Comment: Indeed. If OP wants a seasonal comparison, here's the sheet music for [What Child Is This?](https://www.8notes.com/scores/1577.asp) in E minor with a lovely D# near the end of each phrase.

Comment: Isn't the nat.7th of Em D nat? (1st para). Did you mean D#? It's probably the way it's phrased - the *normal seventh* note in Em is D# - apart from the Dnat found in E natural minor. That's just dinged an alarm bell. Imagine the scale 'A flat natural minor' Sounds like a contradiction in terms!

Comment: @Tim I see the potential for confusion, so I'd just say *naturalised seventh* or *raised seventh*. The natural seventh would be D♯ (the 7th is D, naturalised up to D♯ even though it has a sharp). I and many others call it that way because major scales include a natural seventh, not a sharp one. Also, the sharp 7th would just be enharmonic to the octave. "A flat natural minor" is weird, but completely standard

Comment: @Tim also, this makes a lot more sense in keys like D♭minor, where C♮ is the natural 7th. I guess another way to look at it is that in natural minor, the 7th degree is flattened, and undoing that takes a natural, not a sharp.

Comment: It's just, maybe only to me, but C maj and several of the 'flat' keys (F, Bb, Eb etc)all have a leading note that is in fact a natural, whereas all the sharp keys (G, D, A etc) have a sharp (not a natural) for their leading note: major and two minors. I understand the leading note is natural (normal) for any key, it's just that some readers may suffer confusion! Merely trying to make things as clear as poss.

Comment: @Tim I see your point. It's much clearer from a strictly intervallic perspective instead of within any particular key. Point is, the D♯ is part of the **E harmonic minor scale**.

Comment: @user45266 - in reality, the natural minor is just that. The 7th note is as it should be. In the harmonic and melodic minors, that 7th note is raised, rather that the other way round. D# is also (your last comment) part of the **E melodic minor scale**.

Comment: @Tim We're on the same page. I believe we may have confused each other :)